# how to import/Export data from old version to updated version of CiviCRM

Tags: wordpress, upgrade, import

recently I have updated my CiviCRM Plugin in Wordpress.Now how can I import/export data of the old version to the new version?

Comment: How did you perform upgrade?

Comment: It shouldn't be necessary to import/export the data.  As Pradeep is suggesting, it may be you did the upgrade in a non-standard way.